# Desktop freezes after upgrade to 14.10

Tags: kubuntu, 14.10

I upgraded to 14.10 from 14.04. And I use Ubuntu+Kubuntu.
Temporary solution is, after freeze, I do <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (Suspend), and then click Power button (Wake), and everything returns to normal, till next freeze.

Any permanent solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, kinks are introduced when upgrading like that (straight from one version to another, in this case trusty (14.04) to utopic (14.10)).

What I would suggest as a permanent solution is:

- Backup whatever data you want/need to keep.
- Obtain the ISO of Ubuntu Utopic (14.10) and do a fresh install via a CD or bootable USB.
- OPTIONAL: Zero (wipe out your drive with zeros) before installing a fresh copy.

Comment: It is not the solution I am looking for.